# How to get the current default Formatter in MatPlotLib

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to write a [`Formatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#tick-formatting) that preprocesses some its values and then passes them into a different `Formatter` for the actual formatting. I would like to get the default `Formatter` that would be assigned to new axes. How do I do this without creating a temporary `Axis` object?

I was unable to find anything in the documentation. [`matplotlibrc`](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) seems like one place where such a thing would be listed, but there only appear to be `axes.formatter.*` keys for `Formatter` parameters, not the class itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source code, the default formatter is actually hard-coded into the [`axis.cla`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axis.py) method:

```
 def cla(self):
    'clear the current axis'
    self.set_major_locator(mticker.AutoLocator())
    self.set_major_formatter(mticker.ScalarFormatter())
    ...
```

Comment: @tacaswell. Is this something that ought to be changed?